# Django running a python function from views using checkbox widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a Django project. I have a lot data in my database and I am rendering it to my template through a table. Each column corresponds to the fields in my database. Along with that, my app allows the user to perform some actions to selected data. I want to allow the user to be able to run those actions (through functions from the `views`) with a click of a button.

Quite obviously, it would be tedious to have the user click on a button for every row. So I thought it was best to have them click on the checkbox for the respective row and then have them click on a button to run a specific function from my project.

Forgive me, but I don't how to approach this kind of set up. I have read about the checkbox widget but how can I run a function to a set of objects that are being rendered on the HTML template, given they have a check on the checkbox.

Thanks for your guidance!

---

Here is my template snippet of what I have:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Major</th>
            <th scope="col">Promote</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for s in list %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{s.student_id}}</th>
                <td>{{s.user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{s.user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{s.major}}</td>
               <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'emailPage' s.student_id%}">Make Tutor</a></td> 
            </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Trying to replace the every row button to a one-button click system. I pass masterList from my views.

models.py

```
class masterList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")

    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, validators=[MaxValueValidator(999999), MinValueValidator(100000)])
    phone = PhoneField(blank=False, help_text='best number to contact you')
    major = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    eof = models.BooleanField(blank=False, choices = [(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')])
    arc = models.BooleanField(blank=False, choices = [(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')])

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Student Info'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: would you be able to post some code snippets to help clarify the data structures being displayed to the user and the methods being used to alter the data. you described clicking buttons and buttons being assigned to rows, however I am struggling to visualize your current state and end goal.

Comment: @Display_name I updated my post

Comment: you say you want " have them click on the checkbox for the respective row and then have them click on a button to run a specific function from my project. " I want to confirm you mean "row" and not "column". if so, wouldn't it be easiest just to place an html button outside the table and link it to a for loop function in the view? Does this sound like what you want? similar to what's in the Django admin for deleting users?

Comment: @Display_name that's exactly what I want yes.

Comment: @Display_name how would I run some code looping through the view and identifying if it's checked. In the dark for that. Perhaps a demonstration in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on this, I've seen people do it with live reloading and with the logic outside of views (I hear that's looked down upon) but this is the general format I usually string together for things like this:

```
# models.py

class ListModel(models.Model):
    . . .
    student_id = models.Field()


# views.py

    if request.POST.get('expel_all_students'):
        for student_id in table:
            expelled_students_id = str(request.POST.get('expelled_student'))
            expelled_student_instance = ListModel.objects.get(id = expelled_students_id)
            student_id.rm(expelled_student_instance)

# templates.py
<button type="submit" value='expel_all_students' name="expel_all_students"> Expel all students </button>

<table>
    . . .
```

The key take away here is the button value is picked up by the if statement in the view which triggers a function's action when the submit button is clicked. that's the magic my friend.

Comment: This works, but how do I run the function by clicking the button for SELECTED ITEMS i.e. items that were checked by the checkbox